# Calling method of another class JAVA

Tags: java

I'm using an external class that contains the method: public static boolean isPrime(int n).

I'm new in java and I don't know how to call a method from another class, I've been reading in other posts and they suggest to create an object, so that's what I did creating TestPrime objeto=new TestPrime(); but the if(objeto.isPrime(arrayInt[i])==true) isn't working.

```
import com.utad.idcd.redes.PrimeNumber;
public class TestPrime {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        TestPrime objeto = new TestPrime();
        int arrayInt[] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 };
        for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {

            System.out.print("El" + arrayInt[i] + "es: ");

            if (objeto.isPrime(arrayInt[i]) == true) {
                System.out.print("primo\n");
            } else {
                System.out.print("no primo\n");
            }
        }    
    } 
}
```

Comment: Provide a [mcve].

Comment: Where is the `isPrime` method defined?

Comment: The external class defining the isPrime method is named PrimeNumber, right? So the method is in the class PrimeNumber. Not in your own class TestPrime. So calling isPrime() on objeto, which is of type TestPrime, doesn't make sense. The method is static, so you don't need an instance to call it. All you need is  `if (PrimeNumber.isPrime(arrayInt[i]))`.

Comment: Also, don't just say "it doesn't work". Tell us precisely what you're doing, and what happens (including, of course, the exact and complete error messages you might get). Reading and understanding error messages is the most important step in fixing the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to create object of the PrimeNumber Class

```
import com.utad.idcd.redes.PrimeNumber;
public class TestPrime {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int arrayInt[] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 };
        for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {

            System.out.print("El" + arrayInt[i] + "es: ");

            if (PrimeNumber.isPrime(arrayInt[i]) == true) {
                System.out.print("primo\n");
            } else {
                System.out.print("no primo\n");
            }
        }    
    } 
}
```

Now it should run fine.

Edit:
sorry, I did not see the method was static;
since your method is static and public you can also use static import like:

```
import static com.utad.idcd.redes.PrimeNumber.isPrime;
```

and then directly use the function as

```
if (isPrime(arrayInt[i]) == true) {
```

Comment: The method is static. No need to create an instance.

Comment: This could have been a comment.

Answer (score -1):

Please look the example below guy,

class PrimeNumber{

public void boolean isPrimeNumber(){

//Your code check the prime number here

}

}

class MainTest {

```
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    PrimeNumber obj =new PrimeNumber();
    int arrayInt[] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 };
    for(int i=0; i<9; i++){

        System.out.print("El" + arrayInt[i] + "es: ");

        if(obj.isPrimeNumber(arrayInt[i])==true){
            System.out.print("primo\n");
        }
        else {
            System.out.print("no primo\n");
        }
   }    
}
```

}